# Freebsd Common User Access Management (tried with OpenLDAP, not working) (Open to other suggestions)

Tags: freebsd, ldap, openldap

What I have are a large number of servers (all freebsd). I need to build a common user access management for it (as new developers are joining, want to add their access details on 1 server, and no where else). I am thinking (like ldap) that there is a common server where I have a user access management system (like ldap). When a new user who has not yet logged in on a server, comes to login, and that point the system on which the users wants to login, checks in the common user access system, and does the authentication, and then allows the user to login.

Features needed:

1. Support of Public/Private Key for login (to be controlled/validated by the common user access system)
2. Support of 2fa (google authenticator) (to be controlled/validated by the common user access system)
3. Access to a user, to be controlled at 2 level.
   3.1. User does not exist in the common server -> login attempt to be failed.
   3.2. User exists, but does not have login rights to a particular -> login attempt on the blocked server to be failed.
4. If I create a new server, without me personally going and adding all the users, the user authentication should work from the common server (even their directory creation should be automatic, somehow)
5. If I add a new user to the common server then that user should be able to login to any of the servers.

Please suggest how do I go about. I am trying to setup openldap but not able to as no proper step by step guide present for the same. Any other suggestion is also welcomed. I have listed down my requirement, would like to see this fulfilled in one way or other.

I have tried to setup openldap client in freebsd with openldap docker image (setup on a ubuntu server, as docker has some more limitations to be run on freebsd) as the common server, but no guide found for step by step process. Also I did not find any guide on adding the 2fa to be a part of openldap.